How can I read data in a zipapp file?
I have a build directory that contains main.py and config.json
main.py
import os


def main() -> None:
    config = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'config.json')
    print(f'{config=}')
    print(f'{os.path.isfile(config)=}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

When I run the py file in build ,the program reports that config.json exists.
When I build the zipapp file
python -m zipapp build --main main:main --output dist/main.pyz

both main.py and config.json are in main.pyz, but when I run the pyz file it reports that config.json is not a file
How can I read the config file?
I am on a *nix system

Use importlib.resources to access package data, always, not only for zipapps.
